# How to access request body when using Django Rest Framework and avoid getting RawPostDataException

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, http-post

I need to get the raw content of POST request body (as a string) yet when I try to access `request.body` I'm getting an exception:

```
django.http.request.RawPostDataException:
You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream
```

I am aware that it is adviced to use `request.data` instead of `request.body` when using Django Rest Framework, yet for the purpose of validating digital signature I have to have the request body in a raw and "untouched" form, since this is what 3rd-party signed and what I need to validate.

Pseudocode:

```
3rd_party_sign(json_data + secret_key) != validate_sign(json.dumps(request.data) + secret_key)

3rd_party_sign(json_data + secret_key) == validate_sign(request.body + secret_key)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have found interesting [topic](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2774) on DRFs GitHub, but it does not fully cover the problem. I have investigated the case and came up with a neat solution. Surprisingly there was no such question on SO, so I decided to add it for public following the [SO self-answer guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

The key for understanding the problem and solution is how the `HttpRequest.body` ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L258)) works:

```
@property
def body(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '_body'):
        if self._read_started:
            raise RawPostDataException("You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream")
        # (...)
        try:
            self._body = self.read()
        except IOError as e:
            raise UnreadablePostError(*e.args) from e
        self._stream = BytesIO(self._body)
    return self._body
```

When accessing `body` - if the `self._body` is already set its simply  returned, otherwise the internal request stream is being read and assigned to _body: `self._body = self.read()`. Since then any further access to `body` falls back to `return self._body`. In addition before reading the internal request stream there is a `if self._read_started` check which raises an exception if "read has started".

The `self._read_started` flague is being set by the `read()` method ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/http/request/#HttpRequest.read)):

```
def read(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self._read_started = True
    try:
        return self._stream.read(*args, **kwargs)
    except IOError as e:
        six.reraise(UnreadablePostError, ...)
```

**Now it should be clear that the `RawPostDataException` will be raised after accessing the `request.body` if only the `read()` method has been called without assigning its result to requests `self._body`.**

Now lets have a look at DRF `JSONParser` class ([source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/1ca5a9d042aeff9c768e82e7c40254476cbe88f0/rest_framework/parsers.py#L49)):

```
class JSONParser(BaseParser):
    media_type = 'application/json'
    renderer_class = renderers.JSONRenderer

    def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):
        parser_context = parser_context or {}
        encoding = parser_context.get('encoding', settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET)
        try:
            data = stream.read().decode(encoding)
            return json.loads(data)
        except ValueError as exc:
            raise ParseError('JSON parse error - %s' % six.text_type(exc))
```

(I have chosen slightly older version o DRF source, cause after May 2017 there have been some performance improvements that obscure the key line for understanding our problem)

Now it should be clear that the `stream.read()` call sets the `_read_started` flague and therefore it is impossible for the `body` property to access the stream once again (after the parser).

## The solution

The "no request.body" approach is a DRF intention (I guess) so despite it is technically possible to enable access to `request.body` globally (via custom middleware) - it should NOT be done without deep understanding of all its consequences.

**The access to the `request.body` property may be explicitly and locally granted in the following manner:**

You need to define [custom parser](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#custom-parsers):

```
import json
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework.exceptions import ParseError
from rest_framework import renderers
from rest_framework.parsers import BaseParser

class MyJSONParser(BaseParser):
    media_type = 'application/json'
    renderer_class = renderers.JSONRenderer

    def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):
        parser_context = parser_context or {}
        encoding = parser_context.get('encoding', settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET)
        request = parser_context.get('request')
        try:
            data = stream.read().decode(encoding)
            setattr(request, 'raw_body', data) # setting a 'body' alike custom attr with raw POST content
            return json.loads(data)
        except ValueError as exc:
            raise ParseError('JSON parse error - %s' % six.text_type(exc))
```

Then it can be used when it is necessary to access raw request content:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@parser_classes((MyJSONParser,))
def example_view(request, format=None):
    return Response({'received data': request.raw_body})
```

While `request.body` still remains globally inaccessible (as DRF authors intended).

Comment: What is `six`? which used in this instruction `raise ParseError('JSON parse error - %s' % six.text_type(exc))`

Comment: `six` is a Python 2 and 3 compatibility library which was used quite often when Python 2 projects were being prepared for migration to Python 3. Nowadays almost everything is already migrated to Python 3, so you can just remove that. See: https://six.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 9):

I might be missing something here but I'm pretty sure you don't need to define a custom parser in this case...

You can just use the JSONParser from DRF itself:

```
    from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
    from rest_framework.decorators import parser_classes
    from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser

    @api_view(['POST']) 
    @parser_classes((JSONParser,)) 
    def example_view(request, format=None):
        """
        A view that can accept POST requests with JSON content.
        """
        return Response({'received data': request.data})
```

Comment: Yes, in a class-based view you can get at it with `self.context['request'].data` Spent a fair amount of time trying to modify the MultiPartParser in the style of the accepted solution. One line gets it.

Comment: Note that in my case I didn't  want to access `request.data` but raw `request.body`. Request `data` returns python dict with parsed json. While for veryfing signature I had to retrieve the raw request body as a string.

Answer (score 5):

Its been a while since this question is asked, so I'm not sure if theres some differences with the framework at the time, but if anyone is searching for accessing the raw request body with recent versions, from the [DRF docs on the parsers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#how-the-parser-is-determined):

> The set of valid parsers for a view is always defined as a list of classes. When request.data is accessed, REST framework will examine the Content-Type header on the incoming request, and determine which parser to use to parse the request content.

Meaning the parser is executed lazily when `request.data` is accessed. So the solutions can be quite simply to read the `request.body`, and cache it somewhere before accessing `request.data`. No need to write a custom parser.

```
def some_action(self, request):
  raw_body = request.body
  parsed_body = request.data['something']
  verify_signature(raw_body, request.data['key_or_something'])
```

Comment: You would have thought Django would realise the importance of the real body. It's indicative of the Django attitude to control and hide everything that it actually loses this datum. You don't need it right? We do everything for you. No. I hope your solution works. When you start dealing with Middleware you need to preserve the body very early, before there is even any data, and then if later access to the body is needed that needs to be organised with the other components. It gets awkward in an existing app. If Django is going to do everything it should also officially preserve the raw body.

Answer (score 0):

Updated solution with custom parser:

site_root/common/parsers.py

```
import codecs

from django.conf import settings

from rest_framework.exceptions import ParseError
from rest_framework import renderers
from rest_framework.parsers import BaseParser
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
from rest_framework.utils import json


class BodySavingJSONParser(BaseParser):
    """
    Parses JSON-serialized data.
    """
    media_type = 'application/json'
    renderer_class = renderers.JSONRenderer
    strict = api_settings.STRICT_JSON

    def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):
        """
        Parses the incoming bytestream as JSON and returns the resulting data.
        """
        parser_context = parser_context or {}
        encoding = parser_context.get('encoding', settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET)
        request = parser_context.get('request')

        try:
            decoded_stream = codecs.getreader(encoding)(stream)
            decoded_content = decoded_stream.read()
            # Saving decoded request original body to original_body
            setattr(request, 'original_body', decoded_content)
            parse_constant = json.strict_constant if self.strict else None
            return json.loads(decoded_content, parse_constant=parse_constant)
        except ValueError as exc:
            raise ParseError('JSON parse error - %s' % str(exc))
```

site_root/myapp/views.py

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, parser_classes
from rest_framework.response import Response

from common.parsers import BodySavingJSONParser

@api_view(['POST'])
@parser_classes([BodySavingJSONParser])
def view1(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(request.original_body)
    return Response({})
```