# Django body encoding vs slack-api secret

Tags: django, slack-api, url-encoding

I am following the instruction from this [page](https://api.slack.com/docs/verifying-requests-from-slack). I am building a slack slash command handling server and I can't rebuild the signature to validate slash request authenticity.

here is the code snippet from my django application (the view uses the django rest-framework APIView):

```
@property
def x_slack_req_ts(self):
    if self.xsrts is not None:
        return self.xsrts
    self.xsrts = str(self.request.META['HTTP_X_SLACK_REQUEST_TIMESTAMP'])
    return self.xsrts

@property
def x_slack_signature(self):
    if self.xss is not None:
        return self.xss
    self.xss = self.request.META['HTTP_X_SLACK_SIGNATURE']
    return self.xss

@property
def base_message(self):
    if self.bs is not None:
        return self.bs
    self.bs = ':'.join(["v0", self.x_slack_req_ts, self.raw.decode('utf-8')])
    return self.bs

@property
def encoded_secret(self):
    return self.app.signing_secret.encode('utf-8')

@property
def signed(self):
    if self.non_base is not None:
        return self.non_base
    hashed = hmac.new(self.encoded_secret, self.base_message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
    self.non_base = "v0=" + hashed.hexdigest()
    return self.non_base
```

This is within a class where `self.raw = request.body` the django request and self.app.signing_secret is a string with the appropriate slack secret string. It doesn't work as the `self.non_base` yield an innaccurate value.

Now if I open an interactive python repl and do the following:

```
>>> import hmac
>>> import hashlib
>>> secret = "8f742231b10e8888abcd99yyyzzz85a5"
>>> ts = "1531420618"
>>> msg = "token=xyzz0WbapA4vBCDEFasx0q6G&team_id=T1DC2JH3J&team_domain=testteamnow&channel_id=G8PSS9T3V&channel_name=foobar&user_id=U2CERLKJA&user_name=roadrunner&command=%2Fwebhook-collect&text=&response_url=https%3A%2F%2Fhooks.slack.com%2Fcommands%2FT1DC2JH3J%2F397700885554%2F96rGlfmibIGlgcZRskXaIFfN&trigger_id=398738663015.47445629121.803a0bc887a14d10d2c447fce8b6703c"
>>> ref_signature = "v0=a2114d57b48eac39b9ad189dd8316235a7b4a8d21a10bd27519666489c69b503"
>>> base = ":".join(["v0", ts, msg])
>>> hashed = hmac.new(secret.encode(), base.encode(), hashlib.sha256)
>>> hashed.hexdigest()
>>> 'a2114d57b48eac39b9ad189dd8316235a7b4a8d21a10bd27519666489c69b503'
```

You will recognise the referenced link example. If I use the values from my django app with one of MY examples, it works within the repl but doesn't within the django app.

MY QUESTION: I believe this is caused by the self.raw.decode() encoding not being consistent with the printout I extracted to copy/paste in the repl. Has anyone encountered that issue and what is the fix? I tried a few random things with the urllib.parse library... How can I make sure that the request.body encoding is consistent with the example from flask with get_data() (as suggested by the doc in the link)?

UPDATE: I defined a custom parser:

```
class SlashParser(BaseParser):
"""
Parser for form data.
"""
media_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):
    """
    Parses the incoming bytestream as a URL encoded form,
    and returns the resulting QueryDict.
    """
    parser_context = parser_context or {}
    request = parser_context.get('request')
    raw_data = stream.read()
    data = QueryDict(raw_data, encoding='utf-8')
    setattr(data, 'raw_body', raw_data) # setting a 'body' alike custom attr with raw POST content
    return data
```

To test based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662496/how-to-access-request-body-when-using-django-rest-framework-and-avoid-getting-ra) and the raw_body in the custom parser generates the exact same hashed signature as the normal "body" but again, copy pasting in the repl to test outside the DRF works. Pretty sure it's an encoding problem but completely at loss...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem which is very frustrating.

It turns out that the signing secret was stored in too short a str array and were missing trailing characters which obviously, resulted in bad hashing of the message.